# Tradingview - Set up alerts when draw conditions were met

Tags: pine-script, trading, forex

I have a problem, the script below find divergence, hidden or not, on any given timeframe 4 forex trading. the alert menu don't give me the possibility of setting properly an alert when divergence is founded and drawed on the indicator. I need to activate alerts when "plotshape" draw the line of finded divergences. any help? Thank u

this is the srcipt

```
//@version=4
study(title="Divergence Indicator", format=format.price)

len = input(title="RSI Period", minval=1, defval=14)
src = input(title="RSI Source", defval=close)
lbR = input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=false)
plotBear = input(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=false)

bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

osc = rsi(src, len)

plot(osc, title="RSI", linewidth=2, color=#8D1699)
hline(50, title="Middle Line", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
obLevel = hline(70, title="Overbought", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
osLevel = hline(30, title="Oversold", linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
fill(obLevel, osLevel, title="Background", color=#9915FF, transp=90)

plFound = na(pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish

// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish Label",
     text=" Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bullish

// Osc: Lower Low
oscLL = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low
priceHL = low[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish Label",
     text=" H Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish

// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

plot(
     phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish Label",
     text=" Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bearish

// Osc: Higher High
oscHH = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High
priceLH = high[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(
     phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish Label",
     text=" H Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )
```

EDIT
With this code at the boottom i think it will go. 
Thnak u guys

```
alertcondition(hiddenBearCond, title='Hidden Bear Divergence', message='Hidden Bear Divergence'),
alertcondition(bearCond, title='Bear Divergence', message='Bear Divergence'),
alertcondition(hiddenBullCond, title='Hidden Bull Divergence', message='Hidden Bull Divergence'),
alertcondition(bullCond, title='Bull Divergence', message='Bull Divergence')
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT at us when posting here..Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't help you get an answer faster. It's also rather impolite to be SHOUTING at people you're asking for free help. Thanks.

Comment: Your code isn't complete and doesn't contain the `plotshape()` call you're referring to. If your calls use a boolean variable to trigger, `cond` for example, then proper syntax for the alert could be `alertcondition(cond, "Alert")`. See: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_alertcondition